# Differences between subgroup analysis results from meta and metafor packages

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I am doing a meta analysis using R. After running an overall random effect model I wanted to look at subgroups in a mixed-effect model and was using the `meta` and `dmetar` package ([Doing Meta Analysis in R](https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/mixed.html)), using the `metagen()`function which worked fine.
However, I might have issues with 1) non-independend data and 2) also correlated sampling errors in some cases. Thus, I thought about switching to the `metafor` package to use 1) the `rma.mv()` function to account for the non-independet data and using a 3-level model and 2) use the `robust ()` function for the cases where I have correlated sampling errors.

In doing so I compared the `metagen` with the `rma` model. I could get similar results for the basic (reduced) random effects model.
But when I run the mixed-effect subgroup analysis I get very different results. I'm trying to figure out why because using one package indicates there is a significant heterogeneity between the groups whereas the other doesn’t. Does anyone have any experience with these packages to know why?

Then I ran a random effects model with `metagen ()` ...

```
MA1 <- metagen(TE, seTE, data = mydata, studlab = paste(ID),comb.fixed = FALSE,comb.random = TRUE,
             method.tau = "REML",  hakn = FALSE, sm = "SMD")
```

and `rma ()`

```
MA2 <- rma(TE, var, data = mydata, method="REML")
```

This yields the same results.

However if I do this:

```
MA1.taxa <- metagen(TE, seTE, data = mydata, studlab = paste(ID), comb.fixed = FALSE, comb.random = TRUE, method.tau = "REML",  hakn = FALSE, sm = "SMD", byvar = Taxa)
```

and the same using `rma`:

```
MA2.taxa <- rma(TE, var, mod= ~Taxa, data = mydata, method = "REML")
```

I get very different results.
It would be great if someone could help me out here. I have the feeling it might have something to do with some of the arguments which I didn’t specify correctly. But in looking in the packages I couldn’t figure it out.

This is my data frame:

```
**"ID"**|**"Study"**|**"Organism"**|**"Taxa"**|**"Species"**|**"Ne"**|**"Me"**|**"Se"**|**"Nc"**|**"Mc"**|**"Sc"**|**"TE"**|**"seTE"**|**"var"**
:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:
1|1|1|"A "|"F"|10|259.5|41.1096|10|405.5|15.8114|-4.48970286181781|0.86566827459304|0.74938156163689
2|1|1|"A "|"F"|10|285.9|12.6491|10|452.5|15.8114|-11.1441917779727|1.89336302866627|3.58482355832032
3|1|1|"A "|"F"|10|301.5|12.6491|10|459.1|12.6491|-11.9329315975384|2.02012537466928|4.08090652938268
4|2|2|"B "|"N"|8|40.58|8|8|565.3|8|-62.0123636363636|11.6055591474517|134.689003125
5|2|3|"B "|"Q"|8|15.59|1|8|436.2|5|-110.293157961666|20.6281624673369|425.521086778846
6|2|4|"B "|"R"|8|40.58|8|8|565.3|8|-62.0123636363636|11.6055591474517|134.689003125
7|3|5|"B "|"C"|4|1.887|1.9|4|519.3|26|-24.40757392403|7.05271437893494|49.7407801108356
8|3|6|"B "|"J"|4|18.4|1.5|4|519.3|24|-25.6159441945354|7.39845232761053|54.7370968439256
9|4|7|"B "|"K"|6|0.8174|2.4495|6|296.3|3.1843|-96.0142079773492|21.2399012943102|451.133406992038
10|5|8|"B "|"G"|12|20.2|2.4744|12|30.05|5.8324|-2.12287801050705|0.517088404453606|0.267380418020376
11|6|9|"C"|"A"|4|317.4|44|4|509.2|20|-4.88010696352562|1.5711445799467|2.46849529109589
12|6|10|"C"|"B"|4|333.3|20|4|541.8|16|-10.0108579072198|2.96371122455629|8.78358422256097
13|7|11|"B "|"S"|5|93|8.9443|5|477|11.1803|-34.2583184199475|8.50469827426505|72.329892736287
14|8|12|"B "|"H"|8|175.4|19.799|8|330.4|19.799|-7.4016594042858|1.4714809993973|2.16525633158727
15|9|13|"C"|"E"|6|353|7|6|584|14|-19.2655685142566|4.2992247363139|18.4833333333333
16|10|14|"C"|"O"|5|307.3|8|5|546.798|16|-17.1016587915647|4.28074511636117|18.32477875125
17|11|15|"B "|"D"|12|85.77|9|12|954.8|9|-93.2292720306513|13.9430530966266|194.40872965535
18|11|15|"B "|"D"|12|105.5|9|12|943.5|9|-89.9003831417625|13.4456304955873|180.784979423868
19|11|16|"B "|"I"|12|519.1|9|12|834.2|9|-33.8038314176245|5.06988227434525|25.7037062757202
20|11|16|"B "|"I"|12|504.6|9|12|861.6|9|-38.2988505747126|5.73992676427664|32.9467592592593
21|12|17|"B "|"M"|10|60|12.6491|6|187|31.8434|-5.56823589086092|1.16215466879402|1.35060347419974
22|12|17|"B "|"M"|10|74.6|12.6491|6|227|31.8434|-6.6818830690331|1.35186377624163|1.82753566951429
23|12|17|"B "|"M"|10|92.5|18.9737|12|276|13.8564|-10.7914331134072|1.74445205185438|3.04311296121895
24|13|18|"B "|"P"|6|334.7|29.3939|6|405.3|12.2474|-2.89426691425862|0.861952319419821|0.742961800953209
25|13|19|"B "|"P"|6|397.7|12.2474|6|407.5|39.1918|-0.311566458691052|0.581446713087198|0.338080280159906
26|14|20|"B "|"L"|3|216|36.3731|3|356|39.8372|-2.93620355270232|1.33762126119416|1.78923063839866
27|15|21|"B "|"P"|13|153.4|69.2266|19|163.1|51.8709|-0.159116969627101|0.360514880984436|0.129970979411222
28|16|22|"B "|"M"|5|124.6|2.2361|5|665.6|2.2361|-218.525630021163|54.1029220348491|2927.12617270896
```

Comment: If nobody answers here you could try the R mailing list dedicated to meta-analysis https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// where the authors of both packages frequently post.

Answer (score 2):

The meta-regression model fitted via `rma()` assumes that there is one common $\tau^2$ value within the subgroups, while `metagen()` with `byvar` allows $\tau^2$ to differ between subgroups. An illustration:

```
library(metafor)
library(meta)

dat <- dat.bcg
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat)
dat$sei <- sqrt(dat$vi)
```

First, we fit the meta-regression model with `rma()`. I will remove the intercept term, so that the model coefficients are the estimated average effects for each level of the moderator:

```
rma(yi, vi, data=dat, mods = ~ 0 + alloc)
```

These are the results:

```
Mixed-Effects Model (k = 13; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     0.3615 (SE = 0.2111)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             0.6013
I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 88.77%
H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   8.91

Test for Residual Heterogeneity:
QE(df = 10) = 132.3676, p-val < .0001

Test of Moderators (coefficients 1:3):
QM(df = 3) = 15.9842, p-val = 0.0011

Model Results:

                 estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub 
allocalternate    -0.5180  0.4412  -1.1740  0.2404  -1.3827   0.3468      
allocrandom       -0.9658  0.2672  -3.6138  0.0003  -1.4896  -0.4420  *** 
allocsystematic   -0.4289  0.3449  -1.2434  0.2137  -1.1050   0.2472      

---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Now the same analysis using `metagen()`:

```
metagen(yi, sei, data=dat, comb.fixed=FALSE, method.tau="REML", byvar=alloc)
```

These are the results:

```
Number of studies combined: k = 13

                                         95%-CI     z  p-value
Random effects model -0.7145 [-1.0669; -0.3622] -3.97 < 0.0001

Quantifying heterogeneity:
 tau^2 = 0.3132 [0.1197; 1.1115]; tau = 0.5597 [0.3460; 1.0543];
 I^2 = 92.1% [88.3%; 94.7%]; H = 3.56 [2.93; 4.34]

Quantifying residual heterogeneity:
 I^2 = 92.4% [88.4%; 95.1%]; H = 3.64 [2.94; 4.50]

Test of heterogeneity:
      Q d.f.  p-value
 152.23   12 < 0.0001

Results for subgroups (random effects model):
                     k                     95%-CI  tau^2    tau      Q   I^2
alloc = random       7 -0.9710 [-1.5118; -0.4301] 0.3925 0.6265 110.21 94.6%
alloc = alternate    2 -0.5408 [-1.0927;  0.0111] 0.1326 0.3641   5.56 82.0%
alloc = systematic   4 -0.4242 [-1.1293;  0.2809] 0.4003 0.6327  16.59 81.9%

Test for subgroup differences (random effects model):
                    Q d.f. p-value
Between groups   1.86    2  0.3943
```

We see minor differences between the `Model Results` versus the `Results for subgroups` output.

One can fit a meta-regression model that allows for different $\tau^2$ values across subgroups with:

```
rma.mv(yi, vi, data=dat, mods = ~ 0 + alloc, random = ~ alloc | trial, struct="DIAG")
```

The results are then:

```
Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 13; method: REML)

Variance Components:

outer factor: trial (nlvls = 13)
inner factor: alloc (nlvls = 3)

            estim    sqrt  k.lvl  fixed       level 
tau^2.1    0.1326  0.3641      2     no   alternate 
tau^2.2    0.3925  0.6265      7     no      random 
tau^2.3    0.4003  0.6327      4     no  systematic 

Test for Residual Heterogeneity:
QE(df = 10) = 132.3676, p-val < .0001

Test of Moderators (coefficients 1:3):
QM(df = 3) = 17.4587, p-val = 0.0006

Model Results:

                 estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub 
allocalternate    -0.5408  0.2816  -1.9204  0.0548  -1.0927   0.0111    . 
allocrandom       -0.9710  0.2760  -3.5185  0.0004  -1.5118  -0.4301  *** 
allocsystematic   -0.4242  0.3597  -1.1792  0.2383  -1.1293   0.2809      

---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

These results are now identical to the ones from `metagen()`.

Comment: Thank you @Wolfgang, that clarified a lot. I changed my code and got similar results. I have a couple of follow up questions. 1) Is the `mods= ~0+alloc` the same expression as `mods=~alloc-1`? 2) If I would want to add a nested structure to the model to account for non-independend data. Could I change the `inner|outer` structure like this: `rma.mv(yi, vi, data=dat, mods = ~ 0 + alloc, random = ~ alloc | study/trial, struct="DIAG")` I assume trial is a placeholder for a unique ID.